# How to sort QTableWidget by column without clicking on the header?

Tags: python, sorting, pyside, qtablewidget

I have a `QTableWidget` with many columns and I want to allow sorting only by specific columns. Enabling sorting for the whole table with `setSortingEnabled(1)` makes the table sortable by all columns,

In this example

```
Name        Read    Comment
whatever1    0      bla 
whatever2    0      bla
whatever3    1      bla
```

I want to sort the table only by column "Read" and only with the operator `<`.

Is there a function or slot that I can execute after each cell changes?

```
self.ui.table.connect.cellChanged(self.sort_by_read)
```

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973912/pyqt-qt4-qtableview-how-to-disable-sorting-for-certain-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists `PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget.sortItems(column[, order=Qt.AscendingOrder])` for sorting items by one specific column.

http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget.sortItems